# spring integration tcp in-bound block when deserializerd

Tags: spring, spring-integration

and the Deserializer class is :

```
public class XmlPatternPacketSerializerDeserializer implements Serializer<Document>,
    Deserializer<Document> {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

@Override
public Document deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    logger.info("begin deserialize...");

    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document packetDoc = null;
    InputSource in = readSocketInputStream(inputStream);
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        packetDoc = builder.parse(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

    System.out.println("build id >>> " + packetDoc.getElementsByTagName("building_id").item(0).getTextContent());
    return packetDoc;
}

@Override
public void serialize(Document object, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


private InputSource readSocketInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int i = -1;
    while((i = inputStream.read())!=-1){
        sb.append((char)i);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return new InputSource(new StringReader(new     String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))));
}
}
```

the datagram packet is  xml format,when server recive the data,i want to deserialize to a Document object.but unfortunately that the thread was blocked when deserialize .
please help.
integration xml config is here:

```
<bean id="xmlPatternPacketSerializerDeserializer"
    class="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.XmlPatternPacketSerializerDeserializer" />
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverConnectionFactory"
    type="server" using-nio="true" port="${availableServerSocket}" deserializer="xmlPatternPacketSerializerDeserializer"/>
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="tcpInbound" channel="tcpReceive"
    connection-factory="serverConnectionFactory"/>
<int:service-activator id="tcpHandler" input-channel="tcpReceive"
    ref="tcpListener"/>
```

the datagram packet is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<common>
    <building_id>320411D001</building_id>
    <gateway_id>320411D00101</gateway_id>
    <type>continuous</type>
</common>
<data operation="continuous">
    <sequence>1</sequence>
    <parser>yes</parser>
    <total>5319</total>
    <current>93</current>
    <time>20130820160405</time>
    <meter id="0001" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01D10" error="0" unit="kWh">301.83
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0002" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01D10" error="0" unit="kWh">73.49
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0003" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01D10" error="0" unit="kWh">5.16
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0004" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01D10" error="0" unit="kWh">381.72
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0005" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01D10" error="0" unit="kWh">27.67
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0006" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01A10" error="0" unit="kWh">36.41
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0007" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01A10" error="0" unit="kWh">110.03
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0008" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01A30" error="0" unit="kWh">192.25
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0009" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01A10" error="0" unit="kWh">308.17
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0010" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01C20" error="0" unit="kWh">0.00
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0011" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01A20" error="0" unit="kWh">1305.52
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0012" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01C10" error="0" unit="kWh">0.00
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0013" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01C10" error="0" unit="kWh">492.67
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0014" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01D10" error="0" unit="kWh">6009.05
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0015" type="000001">
        <function id="01" coding="01D10" error="0" unit="kWh">62.60
        </function>
    </meter>
    <meter id="0016" type="000002">
        <function id="01" coding="01000" error="0" unit="kWh">237009.5
        </function>
        <function id="02" coding="00000" error="0" unit="">0.265
        </function>
        <function id="03" coding="00000" error="0" unit="">49.99
        </function>
        <function id="04" coding="00000" error="0" unit="W">500.0
        </function>
        <function id="05" coding="00000" error="0" unit="V">233.99
        </function>
        <function id="06" coding="00000" error="0" unit="V">233.69
        </function>
        <function id="07" coding="00000" error="0" unit="V">233.50
        </function>
        <function id="08" coding="00000" error="0" unit="A">0.000
        </function>
        <function id="09" coding="00000" error="0" unit="A">0.000
        </function>
        <function id="10" coding="00000" error="0" unit="A">8.600
        </function>
    </meter>
</data>
</root>
```

Comment: please excuse me that my english is very poor

Answer (score 0):

This implies the deserializer didn't get all the data and is waiting for more.

Set so-timeout on the connection factory to verify and/or use a debugger to step into `builder.parse(in);`.

Comment: i have omission of some message that client send data in interval.any good suggests

Comment: and i don't understand why it needs for waiting until the client closed

Comment: i seem to know why the server is waiting all the time.because it is a long connection,the server doesn't confirm weather the data from client has all come.is it right?

Comment: I can't help you if you don't do what I suggest. I suspect the `packetDoc = builder.parse(in)` is hanging waiting for more data; setting the `so-timeout` will help you discover that.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is first read the data from socket stream into `String` and if end of stream is denoted by `</root>` then close the socket before passing the read data (i.e. string) to

```
Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader(string ) ) );
```

If your server continues to stream many xml messages, then you can build arrary of String objects till server finishes by closing socket.